# Content-Security-Policy for webapp in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, spring, iframe, content-security-policy

I have a webapp (myApp - developed with Spring Boot and Vaadin).
The webapp will be deployed to a Tomcat server: http://tomcatserver:8080/myApp

Now I would like to show the webapp in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) like this:

```
<iframe src="//tomcatserver:8080/myApp"></iframe>
```

One requirement is now, that the iframe should only work for a whitelist of domains which implement the iframe.
So I have a web server http://myWebserver:8081 which has an `index.html` inside the `<iframe>`.

The webapp generates the following in the `WebSecurityConfigureAdapter` of Spring:

```
http.csrf().disable();  // Requirement: DTEUTARIF-111

http.headers()
        .frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
        .headers().contentTypeOptions()
        .and()
        .xssProtection()
        .and()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
        .and()
        .addHeaderWriter(
                new StaticHeadersWriter(
                        "Content-Security-Policy",
                        "default-src 'self';" + 
                            "child-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "script-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "style-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "connect-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "font-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "object-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;"
                        )
                );
```

But I always get this:

```
angular.js:3543 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

And the same for 'script-src'.

I don't know 100%, but when I add `'unsafe-inline'` to ***script-src*** and ***style-src*** the iframe is open for every domain.

What do I wrong? Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 0):

To get a successful solution I replaced :

```
new StaticHeadersWriter(
                        "Content-Security-Policy",
                        "default-src 'self';" + 
                            "child-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "script-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "style-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "connect-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "font-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;" +
                            "object-src 'self' http://myWebserver:8081;"
                        )
```

with

```
new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy",
                        "frame-ancestors 'self' http://myWebserver:8081")
```